# How to Perform Embedding Search for Documents in ChromaDB?

Tags: openai-api, embedding, python-embedding, chromadb, ada-embedding

I've been utilizing ChromaDB for managing my data, employing the source type to insert records into `ChromaDB` collections. However, I need to perform embedding search specifically for documents rather than metadata. Here's the code snippet I've been working with:

collection.add(
documents=["This is document1", "This is document2"],
metadatas=[{"source": "notion", "metadata": "a long metadata......"}, {"source": "google-docs"}],
ids=["doc1", "doc2"]
)

While this setup handles tokenization, embedding, and indexing automatically. I needed to do search for the documents only and not on the metadata.

how to do it?